# Display current location places name ios mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location, checkin

I''m creating a app that already has got a check-in feature based on ios mapkit.
Currently it only displays city and country but my clients want more. 
Het want to be able to check in in places like instagram does.. (with the name of places ex. Restoname..)

I was wondering if this is possible with mapkit library? 
If so does anybody have a code-exemple for this. ??

Comment: Did you try implementing *FourSquare*?

Comment: No I didn''t but I tought it was difficult with swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to work with place marks and annotations. When you create your `MapView` make sure it conforms to the `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        // once annotationView is added to the map, get the last one added unless it is the user's location:
        if let annotationView = views.last {
            // show callout programmatically:
            mapView.selectAnnotation(annotationView.annotation!, animated: false)
            // zoom to all annotations on the map:
            mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can geolocate an address from a string (which would be the address written out like: 123 Fake St., New York, NY ....

```
func createGeoLocationFromAddress(_ address: String, mapView: MKMapView) {


    let completion:CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in

        if let placemarks = placemarks {
            for placemark in placemarks {

                mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
                // Instantiate annotation
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                // Annotation coordinate
                annotation.coordinate = (placemark.location?.coordinate)!
                annotation.title = placemark.thoroughfare! + ", " + placemark.subThoroughfare!
                annotation.subtitle = placemark.subLocality
                mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
                self.centerMapOnLocation(placemark.location!, mapView: mapView)

            }

        } else {

        }

    }

    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: completion)

}

func centerMapOnLocation(_ location: CLLocation, mapView: MKMapView) {
    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Then you can place the annotation on the map by just calling

```
createGeoLocationFromAddress(addressString, mapView: mapKit)
```

This should work. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer.. I was already able to get the adress but not a place-name like apple Inc. or pizzeria ramin... ectt

Comment: @greg - I really don't know how vast their address database is, but I know it will show things like Empire State Building in New York if you use the `placemark.thoroughfare`,  `placemark.subThoroughfare`, and `placemark.subLocality` like the example above. At least it should.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll give it a try.. I''m also experimenting with google places api but can''t get it to work.. I will post a code sample tomorrow, it would be great if you coud have a look..